# How to get all the values of single column using laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, pluck

I am using pluck method to get data from single column

```
$systems = OptionUser::pluck('user_skill');
```

This systems variable returning only one value while I have around 50 values in this table. Please suggest what is correct way to get all the data from this column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please use `get` (which returns simple array of stdObjects) instead of `pluck` (which returns single value - string by default) in laravel 5.4, because of pluck only gives single value from database

```
$systems = OptionUser::select('user_skill')->get();
```

Comment: As of Laravel 5.5 pluck no longer returns a single value, but a collection.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but still if someone need it.

For laravel 4.2 `lists` will work.

Try this : `OptionUser::lists('user_skill');`

> Note:
>
> The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016
>
> The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will work.

```
$systems = OptionUser::select('user_skill')->get();
```